# Powershell Move-Item

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to extract partial filename data from a file and create a folder with its name in another directory then move the file to this location.

I'm also looking to check if this file already exists, if it does it will create one.

So far my code works up until the actual Move-Item itself which brings up a path[0] thing.

```
$TRANSFER = 'C:\Users\BRACEGIRDLE\Favorites\Desktop\TRANSFER'
$TVSHOWS = 'C:\Users\BRACEGIRDLE\Favorites\Desktop\TV_SHOW'

Get-ChildItem "$TRANSFER/*.txt" |
    ForEach{
        $target = $_.Name -split 'S[0-9][0-9].*'
        If( -not (test-path $TRANSFER\$target))
            {
            New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $TVSHOWS\$target
            }
            Copy-Item -Destination $TVSHOWS\$target
        }
```

does anyone have any idea what my problem would be.

Filenames are like such

```
12 Monkeys S02E10 - Fatherland.txt
Colony S02E01 - Eleven Thirteen.txt
Prison Break S05E05 - Contingency.txt
```

The script splits the file name down to the 'TV Show' and creates a folder into another directory with the show name but it wont move the file?

Comment: Maybe `$_ | Copy-Item -Destination $TVSHOWS\$target`? Also check `$target.Gettype()`.

Comment: When unsure what your commands will do append the `-WhatIf` or `-Confirm` parameter and see what the outcome is.

Comment: Hi JosefZ, I tried this and didn’t appear to work..   LotPings, I did try this aswell, it doesn’t show anything other than asking for a path[0] on the copy item command

Comment: Your copy-item is missing a source object, try `Copy-Item -Path $_.Fullname -Destination $TVSHOWS\$target`

Comment: That’s for the reply.. have just tried this and still not working, still getting this path[0] input coming up and nothing is moving

Comment: Apologies I had a typo in My script, ‘whatever’ I tried the -path $_.fullname and still not luck, error changed to just literally a problem with the copy item, in particularly the -path location..?

Comment: could you post the exact error message?

Comment: hi Whatever, this is the error code i recieve... Copy-Item : Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\BRACEGIRDLE\Favorites\Desktop\TV_SHOW\Quantico 
\Quantico S02E10 - JMPALM.txt'.
At line:15 char:9
+         Copy-Item -path $_.FullName -Destination $TVSHOWS\$target
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Copy-Item], DirectoryNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCom 
   mand

Comment: Hi Guys, having looking at the error there is a space in the path ‘Quantico ‘ but looking at the folder created using the same variable doesn’t have the space in it.. I have tried trimming the spaces out but it’s showing the folders names with no space and even using length -1 to try and remove the space and it literally removed the last letter it and leaves the space there.. abit stuck at this point.. does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Anyone have any ideas?